# SCons mwe for a generic Fortran project

Tags: dependencies, fortran, scons, build-tools

I am having a hard time to understand the logic of SCons, even after reading several sources and spending quite some time coding. I have not found any reasonably understandable Fortran project using SCons related to what I want to accomplish. I also found any in-depth tutorial or explanation (the official manual doesn't really tell how things work on the backend).

My **goal** is to automatically compile a Fortran project with source files scattered in a directory-tree starting from some root directory.

An outline of the code:

1. Find all Fortran files in a dir-tree
2. Use `fortdepend` to generate the dependencies and discriminate programs and modules
3. Tell SCons the objects, dependencies and programs/targets

The dependencies among the sources are resolved with fortdepend. But I'm stuck with telling SCons the dependencies. Since SCons has explicit Fortran support, my solution feels way to complicated for such a generic use case.

Here is my `SConstruct` file:

```py
import os
import fortdepend as fd
from  SCons.Environment import Environment

fexts = ['.f', '.for', '.f90', '.f95', '.f03', '.f08']

def find_fortran_files(root_dir, fortran_extensions, abspath=False):
  """Find all Fortran source files in src directory and its subdirectories"""
  source_files = []
  for dir, _, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in files:
      if any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in fortran_extensions):
        source_files.append( os.path.join(dir, file) if abspath else os.path.join(dir.replace(root_dir, '.'), file))
  return source_files

def fortran_source_to_object(source, fortran_extensions):
  """replace the fortran ext with .o"""
  for ext in fortran_extensions:
    if source.endswith(ext):
      return source.replace(ext, '.o')
s2o = lambda src: fortran_source_to_object(str(src), fexts)
ss2os = lambda srcs: [fortran_source_to_object(str(src), fexts) for src in srcs]


def generate_fortran_dependencies(source_files, fortran_extensions, **kwargs):
  """ use fortdepend to get dependencies """
  fproj = fd.FortranProject(files=source_files, **kwargs)
  source_deps, prog_deps = {}, {}
  for key, val in fproj.depends_by_module.items():
    _key = key.source_file.filename
    _val = [v.source_file.filename for v in val] 
    if key.unit_type=='module':
      source_deps[_key] = _val
    elif key.unit_type=='program':
      prog_deps[_key] = _val
  return source_deps, prog_deps

env = Environment(tools=['default', 'gfortran'], F90='gfortran', LINK='gfortran', LINKFLAGS='', F90FLAGS='')

all_files = find_fortran_files(os.getcwd(), fortran_extensions=fexts, abspath=False)
print('- all files found with fortran ext: ', all_files)

source_deps, prog_deps = generate_fortran_dependencies(all_files, fexts)
source_files = list(source_deps.keys())
prog_files = list(prog_deps.keys())
print('- all source deps (no progs)       ', source_deps)
print('- all program deps found           ', prog_deps)
print('- all source files (no progs)      ', source_files)
print('- all prog files                   ', prog_files)

objects = []
all_deps = {**source_deps, **prog_deps}
for src in all_deps:
    obj_path = os.path.splitext(src)[0] + '.o'
    object = env.Object(obj_path, src)
    print(f'-- tell SCons {obj_path} also depends on {all_deps[src]}')
    env.Depends(target=object, dependency = all_deps[src])
    objects.append(object)
print('- all SCons objects', [str(o) for o in objects])

for prog in prog_deps:
  prog_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(prog))[0]
  print(f'-- tell SCons {prog_name} also depends on {ss2os(prog_deps[prog])}')
  env.Depends(target=prog_name, dependency = ss2os(prog_deps[prog]))

# Filter out .mod files from the objects list
objects_for_linking = [str(o[0]) for o in objects] # get only the first entry which is the object file 
print('- all SCons objects for linking', objects_for_linking)

prog_to_make = 'main'
env.Program(target=prog_to_make, source=objects_for_linking)
```

In the below repo https://github.com/alexksr/SconsMWE.git are two python scripts to set up a root directory with example Fortran code. `init1.py` one has dependencies, which are satisfied when compiling in alphabetical order (easy, non-use case). The second `init2.py` has dependencies, that must explicitly be taken into account (`module0` depends on `module1` and `module2`). For the ladder my code does not work, but results in:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
- all files found with fortran ext:  ['./src/module0.f90', './src/main.f90', './src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90', './src/utils/util_module.f90']
- all source deps (no progs)        {'./src/module0.f90': ['./src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90'], './src/module1.f90': [], './src/module2.f90': [], './src/utils/util_module.f90': []}
- all program deps found            {'./src/main.f90': ['./src/module0.f90', './src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90', './src/utils/util_module.f90']}
- all source files (no progs)       ['./src/module0.f90', './src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90', './src/utils/util_module.f90']
- all prog files                    ['./src/main.f90']
-- tell SCons ./src/module0.o also depends on ['./src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90']
-- tell SCons ./src/module1.o also depends on []
-- tell SCons ./src/module2.o also depends on []
-- tell SCons ./src/utils/util_module.o also depends on []
-- tell SCons ./src/main.o also depends on ['./src/module0.f90', './src/module1.f90', './src/module2.f90', './src/utils/util_module.f90']
- all SCons objects ["['src/module0.o', 'module0.mod']", "['src/module1.o', 'module1.mod']", "['src/module2.o', 'module2.mod']", "['src/utils/util_module.o', 'util_module.mod']", "['src/main.o']"]
-- tell SCons main also depends on ['./src/module0.o', './src/module1.o', './src/module2.o', './src/utils/util_module.o']
- all SCons objects for linking ['src/module0.o', 'src/module1.o', 'src/module2.o', 'src/utils/util_module.o', 'src/main.o']
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gfortran -o src/module0.o -c src/module0.f90
src/module0.f90:3:8:

     use module1
        1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'module1.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [src/module0.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Any help is appreciated, before I abandon SCons and go back to make.

**UPDATE**
Issues solved in this [discussion](https://github.com/SCons/scons/discussions/4451#discussioncomment-7921712). Some Fortran-related issues with SCons make this case a special one and SCons does not sticking to the full dependencies.

Comment: Why using this `fortdepend` thing at all? I do not use anything like that. SCons establishes the dependencies due to modules automatically with the exception of some include files. The whole stuff in your question looks very complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to build your test tree:

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'gfortran'], F90='gfortran', 
                  LINK='gfortran', LINKFLAGS='', FORTRANMODDIR='fortran_mods')

sources = env.Glob('src/*.f90') + env.Glob('src/utils/*.f90')

env.Program('main', sources)
```

No need for fortdepend.
Note it was necessary to set `FORTRANMODDIR`, and to not clear `F90FLAGS`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code works with the trivial (alphabetic) dependencies, but not with the ones that need explicit treatment. Running scons on the `init2.py` setup returns `gfortran -o src/module0.o -c -Jfortran_mods src/module0.f90` although `module0` depends on the modules 1 and 2. Thus `Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'module1.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory`. The dependencies are not correctly resolved by SCons itself.

Comment: It might not be dependency resolution. There are some unresolved issues with Fortran modules and module directories which you might be hitting in your more complex setup, particularly if you use a variant directory. You might want to join us over at the SCons project and see if we can help you further diagnose, and whether a couple of pending fixes are applicable to your case (there's a link to a discord server on scons.org, or can use a github discussion if that's easier).

Comment: Okay, after looking, it is a dep problem. SCons has a couple of concepts here which replicate what your `fortrandeps` tool does for make, roughly. There's an "emitter", which decides if extra targets need to be set up. That's what happens when you compile a module source - the `.mod` file is added to the object file in the target list. The "scanner" decides what files a source uses. The Ftn scanner looks for USE and INCLUDE statements, but doesn't add them as deps if they don't exist. That sounds right for INCLUDE, but dodgy for USE. This seems intentional, so not sure it's a Bug quite yet.

Comment: Moved the discussion to https://github.com/SCons/scons/discussions/4451